# Force reload react js component if no change in state

Tags: reactjs

I have api call in my component componentWillMount() section. When i have been redirected from other component to component in which api call is placed. Then it is not going in the componentWillMount section. So is there any function in reactjs, which will force reload my component which will call my componentWillMount function?

Note: I tried this.forceUpdate and ShouldComponentUpdate Method.But didn't seems to work for me.

Comment: `componentWillMount` will be called only once, you need to make it work by using another method.

Comment: Which method? Can you please tell me?

Comment: What handles the redirect? Are you using react router or something similar?

Comment: Yes, Using react router. After getting api repsonse i am redirect user to another component.

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillUpdate` is deprecated. You should make your initial API call in `componentDidMount`. You can make subsequent calls in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)`, where you will have access to both old and new props. Then when the parent component passes in different props you can make the API call again.

For example if you want to make a new API call because the userID changed:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

The parent component is responsible for passing in props that indicate whether an update is needed.

If you really want to “force” an update you could pass in something like `forceUpdate={true}`, but it’s probably better to just pass along whatever info would indicate a refresh is necessary and include the conditional logic in the component itself.

Comment: I am getting another error also listed below:  

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in worksheet (created by Route)

Answer (score 0):

If the component is a "route" component, it will have props from the router which will change when the router updates, which lets you use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function to send a new request.

Be careful to add a check that the location change is what caused the component to update or your setting new state will cause an infinite loop

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.location !== this.props.location) {
    // send new api requests
  }
}
```

If it's not a route component, you'll need to use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) to give it the correct props.

Comment: I don't want to call the api again. If i want to call the api again then i can call it in the componentWillReceiveProps function, which will work fine for me.

Comment: I am getting another error also listed below:

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in worksheet (created by Route)

Answer (score 0):

Extract the code you use to make your API call into its own function in the class then call that both on `componentWillMount` (or better on `componentDidMount` as the first is deprecated in latest React versions) and where you need to re-fetch your data.

For example:

```
export class MyRouteComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null;
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchData();
    // Other stuff when component is mounted.
  }

  componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.location !== this.props.location) {
      // Update data on route change.
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }

  async fetchData () {
    const res = await fetch(...);
    const data = await res.json();
    this.setState({ data });
  }

  render () {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {data == null ? (
          <p>Data is loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

In your case, you could check props (i.e. by using `getDerivedStateFromProps` or `componentWillReceiveProps`/`componentDidUpdate`) and then call `this.fetchData()` so it does refetch your data.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Updated the example as it seems the question is related to `react-router`

Comment: I am also getting another error below:


Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in worksheet (created by Route)

Comment: This errors is pretty self-explainatory but in case you don't understands it, it means that you are calling setState when the component is not mounted, which cause some troubles. To get rid of this error, you need to double check that your API doesn't returns data once component is unmounted. Or that you cancel the fetch promise before navigating away.